# Disable exception messages in output window only for specific portion of the code

Tags: visual-studio, exception, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

In Visual Studio (MSVC) there is an option to completely disable exception messages in output window (`Tools->Options->Debugging->Output Window->General Output Settings->Exception Messages=Off`). Is there a way (perhaps using a `#pragma`?) to disable such output **only** for specific segments of the code?

Use case: `std::stoi()` throws an exception for a non-numeric input that cannot be converted into a number. This exception is then properly caught and handled by my application code. Since this exception happens many times during normal program run and I have caught and handled the exception, I don't want a message about this exception arising from a specific line of code to be polluting the debugger output window, masking some other new exceptions that I should be really paying attention to. I find the debug output to be useful, but once I have properly handled a specific exception, I don't want it to keep cluttering in the debugger output window.

Basically, I would like to have the following:

```
...
//I want exception messages from here
...
try
{
  //I don't want exception messages from here because:
  //a) I have a ton of expected bad inputs during normal program run and
  //b) I have handled these exceptions
#pragma some_magic_pragma_here_to_disable_exception_messages
  auto result = std::stoi(str,pos,base);
#pragma some_magic_pragma_here_to_reenable_exception_messages
}
catch (std::invalid_argument &)
{
  //Do something here
}
catch (std::out_of_range &)
{
  //Do something here
}
catch (...)
{
  //Do something here
}
...
//I want exception messages from here again
...
```

I looked at the [list of MSVC pragmas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword?view=msvc-170), but could not find anything that would remotely resemble what I need.

Comment: `#pragma` are instructions to the compiler, you need an instruction to the debugger.  (Your code is not behaving any differently when exception messages are on or off, the debugger sees the exception in every case and it decides whether to log a message)

Comment: Besides that, exceptions are not meant for "expected bad inputs".  `std::stoi` breaks a whole lot of best practices.

Comment: I agree about the fact that std::stoi() is not perfect, what is the mechanism of your choice for converting strings to numbers?

Comment: IMO `std::strtol` is good -- it handles all the same inputs and errors that `std::stoi` can, just reports failures differently.  (A bit tricky to recognize and distinguish some of the errors, but that's a write-once-with-comment sort of problem)  You also can get better feedback for the user, e.g. if you want "123X" to complain "'X' unexpected in column 4" instead of simply "invalid input", you can do that with `strtol`

Comment: @RegusPregus I think something like preprocessor directives can't control debugger behavior, you can take a look of my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

> **Is there a way (perhaps using a #pragma?) to disable such output only for specific segments of the code?**

**The answer is NO.** VS doesn't design something of this.

The tech you mentioned is another thing, preprocessor directives are instructions to the preprocessor, which is a part of the compiler that processes your code before compilation. They are used to include files, define macros, conditionally compile code, and perform other compile-time operations.

You can take a look of this:

[Preprocessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/preprocessor?view=msvc-170)

The link you shared is actually under this concept.

the debugger is a tool used for finding and fixing bugs at runtime. It operates separately from the preprocessor and compiler.

It is limited to change some settings of the debugger's behavior via UI, the behavior of debugger are not controlled through preprocessor directives.